# What's wrong with my C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, datarow

There is something wrong with my code here:

```
byte[] bits = Convert.ToByte(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Item[0]);
```

There's an error saying that:

> System.Data.DataRow does not contain a definition for 'Item'and no
>   extension method 'Item' accepting a first arguement of type
>   'System.Data.DataRow could be found.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 10):

```
byte[] bits = Convert.ToByte(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Item is not an indexer, it's a function. You should do:

```
byte[] bits = Convert.ToByte(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Item(0));
```

Or if you want item at 0,0 position in your table0 you can do:

```
byte[] bits = Convert.ToByte(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
byte[] bits = Convert.ToByte(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
```

`ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]` returns `DataRow` which has indexer `this[int]` which returns data stored in the column by index.